# JLayeredPane white background next to component

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

Experimenting with layered panes here and I'm having a problem. I have two `JPanel`s. I'm adding them both to a `JLayeredPane` - panel1 is big enough to take up the whole space, while panel2 is smaller and centered using `FlowLayout`. The problem is that with `JLayeredPane`, the background next to panel2 seems to be painted white when I add it. Here's a picture to illustrate. panel1 is blue, panel2 is red:

[image]

As you can see, the bottom part of the panel1 is still painted, but for some reason the sides are just white. The panel2 is 700 pixels wide and centered, while the frame is 800 pixels wide, so it's definitely not a problem with that. Here's the entire class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Errortest extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Creating frame and setting the JLayeredPane as contentpane
        Errortest frame = new Errortest();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLayeredPane pane = new JLayeredPane();
        pane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        frame.setContentPane(pane);
        frame.pack();

        //Creating panels
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        panel1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);        
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700,500));
        panel2.setBackground(Color.RED);       

        pane.add(panel1, new Integer(0));
        pane.add(panel2, new Integer(1));

        frame.setVisible(true);        
    }
}
```

Hopefully that wasn't too confusing. From what I can tell, the white background comes from the `JFrame` itself, since when I do `frame.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);` it turns yellow.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: BTW - why exactly do these panels do custom painting?  If all you want is a color, see `setBackground(Color)`..

Comment: Ah, they do more than just color, but I replaced the actual image with a blank red screen to avoid confusion. The image that's painted on the panel isn't relevant =P

Comment: It is if you don't want other people making the exact same suggestion.  Perhaps not relevant to include in the code, but at least to mention in an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21028551/edit)..

Comment: My guess is your black panel is pushed all the way down to the bottom. You might try drawing a X on the panel spanning the width/height so I can see where the panel truly lies.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Sorry, edited the post with a simpler example. Hopefully this will be easier to understand

Comment: Note that to comply with the 'V' it needs imports as well, but let's go with that.  ..Why is the code/app. using a `JLayerdPane` at all?  What end effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: frame.setVisible(true); must be last code line in current class, constructor, method or void

Comment: @Andrew Thompson please result is finally MCVE ???

Comment: Well, the blue panel is to be there at all times, and the red one is to be toggled on and off, so sometimes it would be hidden (basically a menu). The idea was that this would make sure it's always on the top to avoid it being painted below the blue. But if you have any easier solutions to this, let me know. I'm still a beginner and I like to learn by just doing stuff myself, so I don't follow that many tutorials.

Comment: @mKorbel  If your referring to the MCVE document, yes.  If you are referring to the code shown above, it still lacks a closing `}` ..but I wasn't going to mention that.  ..shhhhh   ;)

Comment: OK.  Now I am finally beginning to understand what you are trying to achieve, I have to admit that I don't often deal with `JLayeredPane` and am not an expert on it.  Perhaps I should leave it to the [layered pane gurus](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jlayeredpane/topusers) to sort out.  ;)

Comment: Now **that** is a nice MCVE.  +1  Oops!  I forgot I'd run out of up-votes for the day.  It is definitely time for bed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a component to a JLayeredPane, it's like adding it to a null layout using container: you must fully specify the component's size and position.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ErrorTest extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Creating frame and setting the JLayeredPane as contentpane
        ErrorTest frame = new ErrorTest();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JComponent pane = new JLayeredPane();
        //pane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));  // Take out FlowLayout
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        frame.setContentPane(pane);

        // Creating panels
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        panel1.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);  // <<<---- Set Bounds

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setBackground(Color.RED);
        panel2.setBounds(50, 0, 700, 500); // <<---- Set Bounds 

        pane.add(panel1, new Integer(1));
        pane.add(panel2, new Integer(2));

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, seems like I figured it out roughly at the same time. Correct answer though, thanks for your help :)

Comment: I needed to figure it out sooner or later for myself. I always dreaded this component. The research was reward enough :)

Comment: Boy am I glad you wandered along and solved this!  I was worried I'd refresh the page and after all my grandiose claims of 'better help sooner' it would have no answers.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found out what the problem is. Has to do with the answer here:
[JLayeredPane not respecting layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025874/jlayeredpane-not-respecting-layers)

> You need a layout manager which understands the Z-Axis. The default layout managers don't understand the Z-Axis of the JLayeredPane.

So it's the FlowLayout that's messing me up. I'll just use absolute positioning for my project and use setBounds() to make sure the red panel ends up in the middle. Otherwise I'd have to look into custom layout managers I suppose.